# Android app development: Change device password?

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the password, or add a password, of an android device in app.

The app I'm making is a device administrator.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287543/screen-lock-password-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely possible. After your app has been granted device admin privileges, then you can execute:

```
mDPM.resetPassword("<new code>", 0);
mDPM.lockNow();
```

mDPM is your `DevicePolicyManager` object.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can prompt the user to supply a password, and you can provide constraints on what constitutes a valid password (e.g., minimum length). However, you can neither add nor change the password directly yourself.

Comment: What about on rooted devices? I know an app that does it, so it must be possible.

Comment: @liamwli: "What about on rooted devices?" -- I have no idea if an app run with superuser privileges can somehow hack into the OS files and add/change a password. "I know an app that does it, so it must be possible" -- name any app that can perform this operation.